# Driver for stamina speed switch

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, sony-vaio

I have a Sony Vaio vpcsc41fm s-series.  With its original system installed (Windows 7 Home Premium) the "stamina-speed" switch was working fine to switch between the two cards I have on my laptop: Intel and ATI 6470.  Now with Windows 8 installed and I couldn't backup the original driver, the switch is not working.  Now I am constantly using ATI 6470 even when I need to use power saving.

Comment: Have you tried the [Win8 video drivers from Sony](http://esupport.sony.com/US/p/model-home.pl?mdl=VPCSC41FM&template_id=1&region_id=1&tab=download#/downloadTab)?  They also have Power Management software?  Not sure what enabled that switch, but updating the drivers would seem like the first thing to try.

Comment: sony sucks ... i have this problem since the day i moved to windows 8 ... you'll have to live with it -_-